# xamarin.forms FlowListView with alternating columns

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using flowlistview with these properties:

```
        <flv:FlowListView
            Grid.Row="1"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            Scrolled="listview_allAds_Scrolled"
            VerticalOptions="Fill"
            FlowIsLoadingInfinite="False"
            FlowItemAppearing="listview_allAds_FlowItemAppearing"                 
            FlowIsLoadingInfiniteEnabled="False"
            Refreshing="listview_allAds_Refreshing"
            FlowColumnCount="2"
            IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
            Margin="5,0,5,0"
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
            FlowItemTapped="listview_allAds_FlowItemTapped"
            HasUnevenRows="True"
            x:Name="listview_allAds" >
```

This displays 2 items next to one another with the layout defined in my datatemplate.

But every now and so often I need to display an item that goes all the way across the screen and isnt in the same layout as the data template selector like so:

[image]

How can I achieve that?

Comment: The purpose of a [DataTemplateSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.datatemplateselector?view=xamarin-forms) is to select between different layouts - so make another template that does what you need. Then override `DataTemplateSelector.OnSelectTemplate`, and add code that returns that template under appropriate conditions.

Comment: That i understand, but that would still render the layout inside one of these columns but I need it to overwrite both columns

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look closely enough at your code. Take a look at [`Flexlayout` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/flex-layout) - might be able to accomplish your goal, with a bit more work.

Comment: To supply an item source to flex layout, see [Bindable layouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts). This supports ItemTemplateSelector.

Comment: WORKAROUND: Looking at github for `FlowListView`, there is a screenshot of what happens with "grouped items" and "Expand" option: given an odd number of items in a group, the last item expands to fill the row. So you'd make your two-column-wide item be the last one in a group (or simply a group by itself). I've seen an answer elsewhere that sets group header height to zero, to hide those headers.